# Files such as libavcodec.so of the Unreal ffmpeg library cannot be packaged into the APK

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, android

I currently use Unreal 4.23.1 to develop Android system programs. I currently use the ffmpeg library to dynamically convert the sampling rate of sound. I add the relevant SO libraries to my Build.cs code. I use UE to package the Android APK program.
There is no problem with packaging, but the SO file cannot be packaged into the APK file, which causes the Android system to crash as soon as I run it. Has anyone encountered such a problem? The programming language I use is C++
Below is the code in my build.cs file

```
using UnrealBuildTool;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class MIC : ModuleRules
{
    public MIC(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;

        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "AudioCapture", "AudioMixer", "WebSockets", "Json", "JsonUtilities", "MediaAssets", "Voice","OnlineSubsystem"});
        
        string ThirdPartyPath = Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "../../ThirdParty/ffmpeg");
        string LibrariesPath = Path.Combine(ThirdPartyPath, "lib");
        string BinariesPath = Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "../../Binaries/Win64");

        PublicIncludePaths.Add(Path.Combine(ThirdPartyPath, "include"));

        // 根据目标平台加载相应的库文件
        if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Win64)
        {
            // Windows 使用的库和 DLL 文件
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "avcodec.lib"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "avformat.lib"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "avutil.lib"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "swresample.lib"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "swscale.lib"));

            PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("avcodec-58.dll");
            PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("avformat-58.dll");
            PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("avutil-56.dll");
            PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("swresample-3.dll");
            PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("swscale-5.dll");

            if (!Directory.Exists(BinariesPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(BinariesPath);
            }

            string[] DllNames = { "avcodec-58.dll", "avformat-58.dll", "avutil-56.dll", "swresample-3.dll", "swscale-5.dll" };
            foreach (string DllName in DllNames)
            {
                string SourcePath = Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, DllName);
                string DestinationPath = Path.Combine(BinariesPath, DllName);

                if (File.Exists(SourcePath))
                {
                    File.Copy(SourcePath, DestinationPath, true);
                }
            }

            foreach (string DllName in DllNames)
            {
                RuntimeDependencies.Add(Path.Combine(BinariesPath, DllName));
            }
        }
        else if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            // Android 使用的 SO 文件
            string AndroidLibrariesPath = Path.Combine(LibrariesPath, "android", "armeabi-v7a");
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(AndroidLibrariesPath, "libavcodec.so"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(AndroidLibrariesPath, "libavformat.so"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(AndroidLibrariesPath, "libavutil.so"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(AndroidLibrariesPath, "libswresample.so"));
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(AndroidLibrariesPath, "libswscale.so"));

            // 这里修改为动态加载 OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay
            DynamicallyLoadedModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay");
            // 可能还需要保留对其他模块的私有依赖
            PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");
            //PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("AndroidAdvertising");
        }

        // 其他配置保持不变
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the provided .so files have been compiled for Android on arm-v7a? BTW: New phone like Google Pixel 7 or 8 don't support arm-v7a (32bit) anymore. So it is recommended to develop new apps for arm-v8a (64bit).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My target Android version is 7.1.1. It is not a mobile phone. The object I am developing is a holographic cabin. Because of the limitations of the holographic cabin Android version, I downgraded from the Unreal version 5.2 to 4.23.

Comment: I will package it in Unreal Engine, which has functions related to Android program packaging. As for whether the SO file you mentioned is compiled for Android, my understanding is that the FFmpeg library I downloaded has a library for the armeabi-v7a architecture, so I will call this library in my C++. According to my understanding, if this library can be packaged into an APK file, this library should be able to run on the Android system. If you have other understandings, I am very willing to communicate with you.

Comment: This problem has been solved. I created an APL XML file and filled it in to find the SO library file in the file when packaging. After packaging, the SO file will be included in the APK file.

Comment: Looks like you have solved your own problem. Feel free to post it as an answer on "Your answer" text form below :)